# Semantic-UI with fixed right menu and grid

Tags: menu, grid, fixed, semantic-ui

I am trying to fixed the menu in the template, but every time when I use the fixed function in the menu, an error occurs because the menu is misplaced to the right off the page.

The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecram/ddbvg532/1/

Reviewing the code and I think the problem is on the Grid.

```
<div class="ui inverted page grid masthead segment">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui fixed inverted pointing menu">
        <div class="header item"><i class="home icon"></i> Principal
        </div>
        <div class="right menu">
          <a class="item"> About</a>
          <a class="item"> People</a>
          <a class="item"> Projects</a>
        </div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I resolve the problem using:
<style type="text/css">.fijo {position:fixed !important; top:0px; z-index:10 !important} </style>

<div class="fijo">
   Content
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem using:

```
<style type="text/css">.fijo {position:fixed !important; top:0px; z-index:10 !important} </style>

<div class="fijo">
   Content
</div>
```